# Change material of scn object programmatically

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit

In my Scene Editor I have cube with a yellow texture with the name of cube.

How can I change the material of the cube in code?

Basically I should look like this:

```
let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/cubeScene.scn")!

var cube = scene.rootNode.childNodes(named:"cube")

cube.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "grid.png")
```

But that doesn't work. What would be the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in your question doesn't compile for three reasons:

1. `childNode(named:)` should be `childNode(withName:recursively:)`. There is both a renamed parameter and a missing parameter.
2. The value returned from [`childNode(withName:recursively:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407951-childnode) is an *optional* node (`SCNNode?`) – since there might not be a node with that name.
3. [`SCNNode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode) doesn't have `diffuse` property. A node *might* have a [`geometry`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407966-geometry) and a geometry *might* have a [`firstMaterial`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scngeometry/1523485-firstmaterial). [`SCNMaterial`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterial) has a diffuse property.

Depending on your needs, the last line could looks something like this:

```
cube?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = /* ... */
```

Note all the question marks:

- There is a question mark after `cube` because there might not exist a node with that name.
- There is a question mark after [`geometry`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407966-geometry) because not every node has a geometry. Some nodes have light or a camera. Some nodes are just part of the node hierarchy.
- There is a question mark after [`firstMaterial`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scngeometry/1523485-firstmaterial) because not every geometry has a material. Also, some geometry elements have multiple [`materials`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scngeometry/1523472-materials).

Comment: Ronnqvist, I have a similar problem, and followed your answer. However, it doesn't seem to be working for me. Could you help me out?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50849501/how-to-access-specific-child-node-scenekit?noredirect=1#comment88707277_50849501