# How to access specific child node Scenekit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

So in my application, you can think that it is similar to blackjack. There is a deck of 52 cards, and you reuse the same design on the back of the card, but it has different card faces such as Ace Spade, 2 Diamond and etc.

So in my Scenekit, I created a scene to specifically design 1 card. I will then duplicate it in my main scene 52 times. I also uniquely identify each individual parent node with a specific name such as Card1, Card2, Card3 and etc.

In my View Controller, I do the act of shuffling the cards in my code, and populate the images of the card face. However, when I tried assigning Card1 with Ace Spade, the rest of the 51 cards are also assigned with Ace Spade.

[image]

**CardScene**: Contains a single card that has a plain front, but designed back of the card.

**Player1Scene**: Adding CardScene to this scene, and duplicate it, because I have more than 2 cards. I'm naming my identity Player1MyCard1, Player1MyCard2 and etc in this scene.

**MainScene**: Contains miscellaneous stuff, including Player1Scene. The codes you see below is done on this scene.

**Problem**

I can't seem to uniquely assign Card1 with Ace Spade, and Card2 with other card faces. What I'm facing is every card faces are assigned with Ace Spade. Below is my code where I try to assign specific faces to specific cards.

```
func SetupNodes(){
    player1MyCard1 = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Player1MyCard1", recursively: true)!
    print(player1MyCard1.name)
    cardFace = player1MyCard1.childNode(withName: "cardFace", recursively: true)!

    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "1Thousand")
    material.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true

    let whiteMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    whiteMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white
    whiteMaterial.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true

    cardFace.geometry?.materials = [material, whiteMaterial, whiteMaterial, whiteMaterial, whiteMaterial, whiteMaterial]
}
```

Comment: Why is this even down voted?

Comment: Is there any chance that your `player1MyCard1` is actually the same pointer at each function call? What happens if you were to add `.clone()` at the end of the first line?

Comment: @Mr_Pouet `player1MyCard1` is unique, and it is the identity of my SCNNode with 2 different geometry attached to it. No function with the same name though. I don't have access to my Mac now. By the way, the codes looks ok to you? Like is my concept of understanding how it works is correct?

Comment: Looking at the code, your materials should be unique, hence why I'm suspecting your card node and/or scene to be the same across multiple function calls. Something unclear from your post is whether you have (1) a single scene with multiple cards or (2) multiple scenes with one card. I would go with solution (1) if possible (or do everything procedurally depending on your constraints).

Comment: @Mr_Pouet I have a `CardScene` where I do the designing of a single card in there. I also created another `Player1Scene` where I drag the `CardScene` into `Player1Scene`. Finally, I have a `MainScene` where it contains miscellaneous stuff like gambling table, other players card and `Player1Scene`. So I do the naming of `Player1MyCard1` SCNNode inside `Player1Scene`, and the code you see above, I'm doing it inside `MainScene`.

Comment: @Mr_Pouet Updated with the structure of my scenes. Hopefully it helps.